# Input a variable into a template<int T>

Tags: c++, templates

I tried to input the variable i

```cpp
int i;
```

into

```cpp
template<int T>
        int ty(){return T;};
```

but i got following errors

```
try.cpp:11:19: Fehler: keine passende Funktion für Aufruf von »ty<i>()«
   11 | std::cout << ty<i>() << "\n";
      |              ~~~~~^~
try.cpp:6:13: Anmerkung: Kandidat: »template<int T> int ty()«
    6 |         int ty(){return T;};
      |             ^~
try.cpp:6:13: Anmerkung:   Herleitung/Ersetzung von Templateargument gescheitert:
try.cpp:11:19: Fehler: der Wert von »i« ist in konstantem Ausdruck nicht verwendbar
   11 | std::cout << ty<i>() << "\n";
      |              ~~~~~^~
try.cpp:9:5: Anmerkung: »int i« ist nicht konstant
    9 | int i;
      |     ^
try.cpp:11:19: Anmerkung: in Templateargument für Typ »int«
   11 | std::cout << ty<i>() << "\n";
      |              ~~~~~^~
```

Full Code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
template<int T>
        int ty(){return T;};

int main(){
int i = 0;
std::cin >> i;
std::cout << ty<i>() << "\n";
return 0;
};
```

Comment: template arguments must be [constant expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constant_expression)

Comment: `i` must be a `constexpr` so you can use it as template parameter.

Comment: Templates are instructions for your compiler to generate code.  Once your program is running, it is too late to request that new code be compiled into the program.